# php file not uploading to temp directory

Tags: php, uploading

//uploadForm.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="browseFile">Filename : </label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="browseFile"><br> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </body>
</html>
```

//upload_file.php

```
<?php
  $allowedExt = array("png","jpg");
    $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    echo "uploading...";
    if((($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"]=="image/jpg")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1000000))
    {
        echo "success";
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "error in uploading" . $_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p>uploaded successfully</p>";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "invalid file" ;

    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]."stored in ".$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]."<br>";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "moved Successfully";

?>
```

When I try to echo the temp directory name , it is blank . The uploaded files are missing .
I dont get it in the `MAMP/htdocs` folder neither in `/tmp/` directory .

I dont have `uploads` directory in `/MAMP/htdocs/` .Wont the program create a directory if it does not exist ?

Comment: And shame on everybody who answered fishing for cheap and easy rep. points.

Comment: @STTLCU and shame on you for explaining nothing to help people learn.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I care more for the value of this community rather than the value of lazy coders. I'll gladly help who shows effort in his/her researches and therefore tho who is actually respecting MY TIME AND EFFORT for answering. Vampires and lazy coders aren't welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your final instructions, you have `$_FILES['name']['tmp_name']` instead of `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.

By the way, you have a few errors in your script:

1. Even if someone uploads an invalid file, you show them an error message, but you still move it to the final place.
2. `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is a value sent by the browser (ie: the client). A malicious attacker may sent you any kind of file and disguise it as a `image/png`, and you are trusting it. You cannot trust this value. Instead, you could use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize), which returns you an array that has the mime type of the image (and is detected by the server (ie: by you). To detect the mime-type of non-images, you can use [`FileInfo`](http://php.net/fileinfo), concretely [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

Also, the php script will not create your `uploads` folder if it does not exist, and instead will show an error (and do nothing). You must create this folder first, and make sure that the user running your php script (usually the same that is running your http server) has write permissions on that directory.

edit: You don't see any uploaded file in your temp directory because (quoting http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of
>   the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"]` does not exist, it should be `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowedExt = array("png","jpg");
echo $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
echo "uploading...";

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```